# PHP Rest api security

Tags: java, php, api, security

We are currently working on a game in java.
For the user authentication we are using a rest api I made in PHP.

I'm using sessions to store the UID and the game stores the session in a [CookieStore](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/net/CookieStore.html).
We've come to the conclusion that this isn't secure enough. We thought about a temporary token, but the 'attackers' will somehow be able to get tokens himself. We could also use an api secret key, but attackers might be able to reverse-engineer the game.

What we want is that nobody can access the api except our game.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could make a one time use token that will be generated on request?
And obfuscate the code.